# I want to get a list of strings from a user, how should i get that?

Tags: python, arrays, lis

I want to get a series of strings from user and put it in a list and then print it

also i want when i put done i close the list and print it

```
list = []
for i in list:

    list[a]=input('the name of stings:')
    list.append(list[a])
    a +=
    print(list)
```

Comment: How many times, do you intend to take input?

Comment: Or what does user enter when he doesn't want to input any more string

Comment: Off-topic but important: don't use `list` as variable name, it will override `list()` in Python.

Comment: Please dont use `list` as variable name. Also your list is empty on start... so the loop is never executed, replace it with the time is sould be executed.

Comment: And your code confused me, what do you want to do? What is `a` and why do you `a += sth`? And why append a list element to itself? Did you really mean to write `my_dict[a]` in the line `list[a]` for a lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
list_ = []
not_done = True
while not_done:
    inp = input('name of string : ')
    if inp.lower() != 'done': # Put any string in stead of 'done' by which you intend to not take any more input
        list_.append(inp)
    else:
        break
print(list_)
```

**Output** :

```
name of string : sd
name of string : se
name of string : gf
name of string : yh
name of string : done
['sd', 'se', 'gf', 'yh']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
n = int(input())

my_list = list()
for i in range(n):
    my_str = input('Enter string ')
    my_list.append(my_str)
    print('You entered', my_str)
    print(my_list)
```

Here is the sample (first line takes number, for how many times you want to take the input):

```
4
Enter string abc
You entered abc
['abc']
Enter string xyz
You entered xyz
['abc', 'xyz']
Enter string lmn
You entered lmn
['abc', 'xyz', 'lmn']
Enter string opq
You entered opq
['abc', 'xyz', 'lmn', 'opq']
```

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-cf42f041f9f1> in <module>()
----> 1 n = int(input())
      2 
      3 my_list = list()
      4 for i in range(n):
      5     my_str = input('Enter string ')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Algeria'

Comment: What did you enter in the first line

Answer (score 0):

```
N = 10  # desired number of inputs

lst = []  # don't use `list` as it's resereved
for i in range(N):
    lst.append(input('the name of strings: ')

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

An example is shown below:

```
input_list = []
while True:
    your_input = input('Your input : ')
    if your_input.upper() == "DONE":
        break
    input_list.append("%s" % your_input )
print("%s" % input_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Your input : a
Your input : b
Your input : c
Your input : d
Your input : dOnE
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```